# Google app engine string to entity

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I want convert any string to my existing Entiy. Is it possible  writing a **convertToEntity**() function as below?

```
class Personel(db.Model):
  name=db.StringProperty()


class IsEntityExists(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    entity="Personal"
    Entity=entity.convertToEntity()
    Entity.all()
```

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if the question is just asking to somehow look up the model class given its name, when it has already been imported.  You can do this easily (but only when it has already been imported!), as follows:

```
cls = db.class_for_kind("Personel")
... cls.all() ...
```

The equivalent in NDB:

```
cls = ndb.Model._kind_map["Personel"]
... cls.query() ...
```

Good luck!

PS. No, it won't do spell correction. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Only if you build loader for models... for example:

```
from app import model_loader

class IsEntityExists(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    Entity=model_loader("Personal")
    Entity.all()
```

while the model_loader function would search the folder structure (python modules) for defined model.. for example you have folder structure:

```
models/
personal.py
other_model.py
user.py
```

So the model_loader("Personal") would import personal.py and extract "Personal" class from that module, allowing you to perform whatever you want with that class - if it finds it and loads it.

Of course you would have to code the loader.

However if the class (defined model) is in the same file as the code, you could search over locals() for "Personal"

```
def load_model(name):
    local = locals()
    try:
      return local[name]
    except KeyError:
      return None
```